# Json.Net: How to validate that there is one to one match between json and C# properties

Tags: json.net

MissingMemberHandling attributes instructs Json.Net to issue an error if json text contains property that is missing from C# class. I want the inverse behaviour as well. I want that Json.Net issues an error if there is a C# property that is missing from json text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I little bit of source digging accomplished with documentation search showed

```
[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.Always)]
```

Applying the above on class marks all of it fields required for de-serialization. As well, `JsonObject` attribute is inherited, what in my case is very helpful.